# Facebook SDK error: init not called with valid version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm implenting a Facebook share dialog to my React site, and I'm receiving the following error when calling FB.ui():

> init not called with valid version

I also manually added `<div id="fb-root"></div>` to my index file before the FB.init() script is ran. I am using a valid version, and all my FB init and share code is taken directly from the Facebook docs.
Has anyone else experienced this bug?
Thanks!

Comment: yup, I just edited my question to include that I already added fb-root. @Tholle

Comment: Have you tried adding `&version=v2.0` to the `js.src` in the script?

Comment: Yup, I add ?version=v2.0 to js.src @Tholle

Comment: That's frustrating. Have you tried the `all.js` script instead of the `sdk.js` script? E.g. `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";`

Comment: Ya it's really frustrating :/ Someone asked the same question on here a couple years ago, and there was no official solution. I tried all.js instead of sdk.js. No luck with that either unfortunately. @Tholle

Comment: Just posted a solution that works for me @Tholle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to remove fbAsyncInit() and instead, add the FB.init properties to js.src like so:

```
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#version=v2.2&appId=myAppId&xfbml=true&autoLogAppEvents=true";
```